# Reference to the tags in pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

How or generally is it possible to reference to the tags from the pom.xml in java? You can make a reference in the pom with e.g.: `<outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}`.

But i want to do something like that:

```
...
System.out.println(${project.version});
...
```

Is this possible?

Comment: no, this is not possible. I only could imagine some hacks with classpath or with parameters

Comment: Can you put together your imagination in an answer ^^?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At build time you can filter some resource files so that at runtime you read the file and get the values you are looking for:

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html

```
  <resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    <filtering>true</filtering>
  </resource>
```

Or if it is more complexe you can use the assembly plugin:

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/examples/single/filtering-some-distribution-files.html

For example:
src/main/resources/info.properties

```
VERSION=${project.version}
```

And at runtime:

```
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.load(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("info.properties"));

    System.out.println(props.get("VERSION"));
```

Comment: I think, that's not really the answer i'm looking for

Comment: Maven variables are only available at build time. So if you need them at runtime, you need to store them somewhere you can read them at runtime.